# R search within loop for different number of rows

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

Can anyone help me with this please.

I am trying to search the columns of a matrix for a certain sum(lets say 120). I just can't figure out it works. It should stop counting within a column as soon as the sum reaches 120. The problem seems to be the second i (a[i+0:i,j]) in my formula messes the whole thing up.

```
a <- matrix(1:100, nrow=10)

a
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100

b <- matrix(ncol=ncol(a), nrow=nrow(a))

for(i in 1:10) {
for(j in 1:10) {
if(sum(a[i+0:i,j])>120) {
b[i+0:i,j] <- a[i+0:i,j]
break}
}
}
```

This is what I get.

```
   b
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
     [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   61   NA   NA    NA
     [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   42   NA   62   NA   NA    NA
     [3,]   NA   NA   NA   33   43   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
     [4,]   NA   NA   24   34   44   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
     [5,]   NA   NA   25   35   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
     [6,]   NA   NA   26   36   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
     [7,]   NA   NA   27   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
     [8,]   NA   NA   28   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
     [9,]   NA   NA   29   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [10,]   NA   NA   30   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

But I would want it to look like this.

```
 b
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   NA   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]   NA   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]   NA   13   23   33   43   53   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [4,]   NA   14   24   34   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [5,]   NA   15   25   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [6,]   NA   16   26   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [7,]   NA   17   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [8,]   NA   18   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [9,]   NA   19   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Thanks for any hint guys.

Comment: `i+0:i` seems wrong. It results in `i+c(0,1,2, ..., i)`. If `i == 6` it will fail because `i+i == 12` and `12 > nrow(a)`. BTW IMHO column must be `1:10` and not `NA` (because `sum(1:10) < 120`).

Comment: yes i+0:i is wrong. But do you have an idea on what else i could put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's the i loop that you want to break, not j, so swap these round - then it looks like you're having problems with indexing in : `b[i+0:i,j] <- a[i+0:i,j]`

try:

```
a <- matrix(1:100, nrow=10)
b <- matrix(ncol=ncol(a), nrow=nrow(a))

for(j in 1:10) {
  for(i in 1:10) {
    if(sum(a[1:i,j])>120) {
      b[1:i,j] <- a[1:i,j]
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well you can try this:

```
max.col(t(apply(a, 1, cumsum)>=120), "first")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a vectorized approach:

```
a <- matrix(1:100, nrow=10)

## use columnwise cumsum
cs <- apply(a, 2, cumsum)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
#  [2,]    3   23   43   63   83  103  123  143  163   183
#  [3,]    6   36   66   96  126  156  186  216  246   276
#  [4,]   10   50   90  130  170  210  250  290  330   370
#  [5,]   15   65  115  165  215  265  315  365  415   465
#  [6,]   21   81  141  201  261  321  381  441  501   561
#  [7,]   28   98  168  238  308  378  448  518  588   658
#  [8,]   36  116  196  276  356  436  516  596  676   756
#  [9,]   45  135  225  315  405  495  585  675  765   855
# [10,]   55  155  255  355  455  555  655  755  855   955

## set cell to NA if the sum of the column is below 120
## or the value is the second value above 120
ifelse(rep(colSums(a) < 120, each=nrow(a)) | cs - 120 > a, NA, a)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#  [1,]   NA   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
#  [2,]   NA   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
#  [3,]   NA   13   23   33   43   53   NA   NA   NA    NA
#  [4,]   NA   14   24   34   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#  [5,]   NA   15   25   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#  [6,]   NA   16   26   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#  [7,]   NA   17   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#  [8,]   NA   18   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#  [9,]   NA   19   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```